# joining strings with a separator and taking into account empty strings

Tags: c#, string, join

I have an object that has a few properties

eg.

```
Employee
-Name
-Company
```

I want to get a formatted string for their firstname and company separated by a "-".

Now I can do a `string.Join("-", e.Company, e.Name)` but if company is null or empty I get "- fred".

Is there a nicer inbuilt way to take into account these blank/empty strings. I was previously using a few short hand ifs to include the - in a string.format but it looks quite messy.

ie.

```
string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", e.Company, !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Company) ? "-": string.Empty, e.Name);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the inline terniary within the `Join` method:

```
string.Join("-", string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Company) ? "fired" : e.Company, e.Name)
```

**Edit (I misread 'fred' for misspelled fired).**
As mentioned in another answer, an extension method would clean up the code. You will be moving ugly code to a different place.

As an alternative to an extension method, I would recommend something like the following that allows for more parameters at a later time:

```
  public static string ExcludeEmptiesJoin(params string[] args) {
     string outValue = string.Empty;

     foreach (var arg in args.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(outValue)) {
           outValue = arg;
        } else {
           outValue = string.Join("-", outValue, arg);
        }
     }

     return outValue;
  }
```

Usage:

```
 Console.WriteLine(ExcludeEmptiesJoin("Company", "Fred"));
 Console.WriteLine();
 Console.WriteLine(ExcludeEmptiesJoin("", "Fred"));
 Console.WriteLine();
 Console.WriteLine(ExcludeEmptiesJoin("Company", ""));
 Console.WriteLine();
 Console.WriteLine(ExcludeEmptiesJoin("Company", "", "4/4/1979"));
 Console.WriteLine();
 Console.WriteLine(ExcludeEmptiesJoin("Company", "Fred", "4/4/1979"));
```

Output:

> Company-Fred
>
> Fred
>
> Company
>
> Company-4/4/1979
>
> Company-Fred-4/4/1979

Comment: He has an inline ternary in his question.

Comment: This looks like a  good way to do it, will test it out and mark correct if its all good

Comment: If you go for this solution I'd suggest to replace 'string.Join' by a 'StringBuilder'.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you're going to simplify this much more than you already have, but if this pattern is going to be used often, you could move the separator handling to an extension method to 'clean it up' a little;

```
static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string RemoveLeadingOrTrailingToken(this string value, string token)
    {
        if (value.StartsWith(token))
            return value.Substring(token.Length);
        if (value.EndsWith(token))
            return value.Substring(0, value.IndexOf(token, StringComparison.Ordinal));

        return value;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s1 = "company";
        string s2 = "product";
        string result = String.Format("{0}-{1}", s1, s2).RemoveLeadingOrTrailingToken("-");
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking the inline ternary out is probably cleaner:

```
= string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Company) ? e.Name : string.Join("-", e.Company, e.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than two attributes, say an address, this solves your problem:

```
List<string> attributes = new List<string>(new string[] {
    e.Company, 
    e.Name, 
    e.Address});
attributes.RemoveAll(s => s == String.Empty);
String.Join("-", attributes.ToArray());
```

Comment: I thought about this but then decided that having to create a list was even more overhead. Thanks for the answer though